# Snake Game: Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a snake game and I am struggling to find some answers as to why I am getting the error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined. I have my javascript source added into my html, but when I try to debug through google chrome, it says my script isn't initiated therefore my functions wont work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>319 Snake</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho&effect=3d-float' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>

        h1 {
            font-family: 'Rancho';
            font-size: 300%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        canvas{
            border: 1px;
            background:#ffffff;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px #000;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
            box-shadow:0 0 20px #000;"
        }
        body{
            background:#cdcdcd;
        }
    </style>
        <h1 class="font-effect-3d-float">Snake 319</h1>
        <canvas id="mycanvas" width="350" height="350" style="border:1px solid #000000></canvas>
    <script src="./snake.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "init();">
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is part of my Java Script code:

```
function init() {

canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

loadImages();
createSnake();
locateApple();
setTimeout("gameCycle()", DELAY);
}
```

Does anyone have any tips as to why my  tag is not working/ where I should put it in my html code.

Comment: Although with HTML5, it may be not necessary, but try including the script with `type` `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: @Variable it says <script src = ...> right before </head>

Comment: @AshishRanjan so something like:    <script src = "./snake.js" type = "text/javascript"></script> ?

Comment: Look at the order of your html code. `h1`, `canvas` are not supposed to be inside `head` but wrapped in `body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing quote and that's why it's not reading your file. It's the following line.

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="350" height="350" style="border:1px solid #000000>    </canvas>
```

On your style tag you are missing a closing `"`

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 3):

The  element is not made for receive `h1` or `canvas` tag. This is a no displayed area. You should put the code which need to be displayed in the `body` part.

Then you are missing quote in your canvas element. See the new code :

```js
function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  loadImages();
  createSnake();
  locateApple();
  setTimeout("gameCycle()", DELAY);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>319 Snake</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho&effect=3d-float' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
      h1 {
        font-family: 'Rancho';
        font-size: 300%;
        text-align: center;
      }

      canvas {
        border: 1px;
        background: #ffffff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
        "

      }

      body {
        background: #cdcdcd;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body onload="init();">
    <h1 class="font-effect-3d-float">Snake 319</h1>
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="350" height="350" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>

    <script src="./snake.js "></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been staring forever and didn't notice the missing quote